# C# dynamic object initializer won't compile

Tags: c#, dynamic, c#-4.0

The following code seems reasonable to me. It should create the object and then use the dynamic features to let me assign any properties I like. However the compiler says that "ExpandoObject does not contain a definition for Test". To which I say, "I know, that's the freaking point!"

```
dynamic example = new ExpandoObject
{
  Test = "fail"
};
```

Any ideas why csc isn't allowing this.

The alternative is to manually expand the code into individual property assignments.

```
dynamic example = new ExpandoObject();
example.Test = "fail";
```

Which is annoying when I have lots of properties to assign.

Comment: Please vote for this feature in Visual Studio [UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/7062098-support-object-initializers-on-expandoobjects).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Within the object initializer, the type is `ExpandoObject`, not `dynamic`, so you don't get dynamic functionality.  *After* the initializer, you are operating on a variable of type `dynamic` and so dynamic functionality *is* available there.

Comment: Ah, yes that makes sense. The object initializer _expression_ is not typed as dynamic.

Answer (score 7):

In your first example, the C# compiler will look for a property named Test on the ExpandoObject. It doesn't exist.

In your second example, the compiler will look for a Test property on a dynamic object. This is allowed, so it compiles.