# How can I use collection initializer syntax with ExpandoObject?

Tags: c#, dynamic, syntactic-sugar, expandoobject, object-initializer

I've noticed that the new `ExpandoObject` implements `IDictionary<string,object>` which has the requisite `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` and `Add(string, object)` methods and so it should be possible to use the collection initialiser syntax to add properties to the expando object in the same way as you add items to a dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string,object> dict = new Dictionary<string,object>() 
{
    { "Hello", "World" }
};

dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject()
{
    { "foo", "hello" },
    { "bar", 42 },
    { "baz", new object() }
};

int value = obj.bar;
```

But there doesn't seem to be a way of doing that. Error:

> 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'Add'

I assume this doesn't work because the interface is implemented explicitly.
but is there any way of getting around that? This works fine,

```
IDictionary<string, object> exdict = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>();
exdict.Add("foo", "hello");
exdict.Add("bar", 42);
exdict.Add("baz", new object());
```

but the collection initializer syntax is much neater.

Comment: Please vote for this feature in Visual Studio [UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/7062098-support-object-initializers-on-expandoobjects).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216309/c-sharp-dynamic-object-initializer-wont-compile

Answer (score 6):

I've had the need for a simple ExpandoObject initializer several times before and typically use the following two extension methods to accomplish something like initializer syntax:

```
public static KeyValuePair<string, object> WithValue(this string key, object value)
{
    return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(key, value);
}

public static ExpandoObject Init(
    this ExpandoObject expando, params KeyValuePair<string, object>[] values)
{
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in values)
    {
        ((IDictionary<string, Object>)expando)[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
    }
    return expando;
}
```

Then you can write the following:

```
dynamic foo = new ExpandoObject().Init(
    "A".WithValue(true),
    "B".WithValue("Bar"));
```

In general I've found that having an extension method to build `KeyValuePair<string, object>` instances from a string key comes in handy. You can obviously change the name to something like `Is` so that you can write `"Key".Is("Value")` if you need the syntax to be even more terse.

Comment: I got a little simpler syntax using reflection. [See](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28375824/450913).

Answer (score 4):

The language specification (7.5.10.3 on Collection Initializers) is a bit vague on this point as far as I can tell. It says

> For each specified element in order,
>   the collection initializer invokes an
>   Add method on the target object with
>   the expression list of the element
>   initializer as argument list, applying
>   normal overload resolution for each
>   invocation. Thus, **the collection
>   object must contain an applicable Add
>   method for each element initializer**.

Unfortunately the text doesn't go into details about what an applicable Add method is, but it seems that explicitly implemented interface methods don't fit the bill as they are essentially considered private (see 13.4.1):

> It is not possible to access an
>   explicit interface member
>   implementation through its fully
>   qualified name in a method invocation,
>   property access, or indexer access. An
>   explicit interface member
>   implementation can only be accessed
>   through an interface instance, and is
>   in that case referenced simply by its
>   member name.
>
> ...
>
> Explicit interface member
>   implementations have different
>   accessibility characteristics than
>   other members. Because explicit
>   interface member implementations are
>   never accessible through their fully
>   qualified name in a method invocation
>   or a property access, they are in a
>   sense private. However, since they can
>   be accessed through an interface
>   instance, they are in a sense also
>   public.

Comment: This is one of the things I really wish they would fix in the next version of C#!

Answer (score 3):

The opensource framework [Dynamitey](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey) has an alternative [syntax](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey/wiki/UsageBuilder) for building `ExpandoObject` instances inline.

```
    dynamic obj = Builder.New<ExpandoObject>(
        foo:"hello",
        bar: 42 ,
        baz: new object()
    );

    int value = obj.bar;
```

It also has a dictionary based dynamic prototype object `Dynamitey.DynamicObjects.Dictionary` such that

```
    dynamic obj = new Dynamitey.DynamicObjects.Dictionary()
    {
        { "foo", "hello" },
        { "bar", 42 },
        { "baz", new object() }
    };

    int value = obj.bar;
```

works too.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are spot on. The `IDictionary<string,object>` has been implemented explicitly.

You do not even need casting. This works:

```
IDictionary<string,object> exdict = new ExpandoObject()
```

<s>Now the reason collection syntax does not work is because that is an implementation in the `Dictionary<T,T>` **constructor** and not part of the interface hence it will not work for expando.</s>

Wrong statement above. You are right, it uses add function:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
Dictionary<string,object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                                                {
                                                    {"Ali", "Ostad"}
                                                };
}
```

Gets compiled to

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       27 (0x1b)
  .maxstack  3
  .locals init ([0] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string,object> dictionary,
           [1] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string,object> '<>g__initLocal0')
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  newobj     instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string,object>::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  stloc.1
  IL_0007:  ldloc.1
  IL_0008:  ldstr      "Ali"
  IL_000d:  ldstr      "Ostad"
  IL_0012:  callvirt   instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string,object>::Add(!0,
                                                                                                                 !1)
  IL_0017:  nop
  IL_0018:  ldloc.1
  IL_0019:  stloc.0
  IL_001a:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

---

## UPDATE

The main reason is `Add` has been implemented as `protected` (with no modifier which becomes `protected`).

Since `Add` is **not visible** on `ExpandoObject`, it cannot be called as above.

Comment: I believe you're mistaken. If I create a class which implements e.g. `IDictionary<string, object>` as in the example I am allowed to use a collection initializer like `var x = new MyDict() { { "foo", "bar " } };`

Comment: What do you mean by it's implemented in the constructor?

Answer (score 2):

It's a shame that adding dynamic properties (whose name is known only at run-time) to `ExpandoObject` is not as easy as it should have been. All the casting to dictionary is plain ugly. Never mind you could always write a custom `DynamicObject` that implements `Add` which helps you with neat object initializer like syntax.

A rough example:

```
public sealed class Expando : DynamicObject, IDictionary<string, object>
{
    readonly Dictionary<string, object> _properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        return _properties.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out result);
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        if (binder.Name == "Add")
        {
            var del = value as Delegate;
            if (del != null && del.Method.ReturnType == typeof(void))
            {
                var parameters = del.Method.GetParameters();
                if (parameters.Count() == 2 && parameters.First().ParameterType == typeof(string))
                    throw new RuntimeBinderException("Method signature cannot be 'void Add(string, ?)'");
            }
        }
        _properties[binder.Name] = value;
        return true;
    }



    object IDictionary<string, object>.this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            return _properties[key];
        }
        set
        {
            _properties[key] = value;
        }
    }

    int ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.Count
    {
        get { return _properties.Count; }
    }

    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    ICollection<string> IDictionary<string, object>.Keys
    {
        get { return _properties.Keys; }
    }

    ICollection<object> IDictionary<string, object>.Values
    {
        get { return _properties.Values; }
    }



    public void Add(string key, object value)
    {
        _properties.Add(key, value);
    }

    bool IDictionary<string, object>.ContainsKey(string key)
    {
        return _properties.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    bool IDictionary<string, object>.Remove(string key)
    {
        return _properties.Remove(key);
    }

    bool IDictionary<string, object>.TryGetValue(string key, out object value)
    {
        return _properties.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    void ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.Add(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
    {
        ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>)_properties).Add(item);
    }

    void ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.Clear()
    {
        _properties.Clear();
    }

    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.Contains(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
    {
        return ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>)_properties).Contains(item);
    }

    void ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.CopyTo(KeyValuePair<string, object>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>)_properties).CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.Remove(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
    {
        return ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>)_properties).Remove(item);
    }

    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, object>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _properties.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable)_properties).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

And you could call like you wanted:

```
dynamic obj = new Expando()
{
    { "foo", "hello" },
    { "bar", 42 },
    { "baz", new object() }
};

int value = obj.bar;
```

The caveat with this approach is that you cannot add `Add` "method" with the same signature as Dictionary.Add to your expando object since it is already a valid member of the `Expando` class (which was required for the collection initializer syntax). The code throws an exception if you do

```
obj.Add = 1; // runs
obj.Add = new Action<string, object>(....); // throws, same signature
obj.Add = new Action<string, int>(....); // throws, same signature for expando class
obj.Add = new Action<string, object, object>(....); // runs, different signature
obj.Add = new Func<string, object, int>(....); // runs, different signature
```

---

If property names needn't be truly dynamic then another alternative is to have a `ToDynamic` extension method so that you can initialize in-line.

```
public static dynamic ToDynamic(this object item)
{
    var expando = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
    foreach (var propertyInfo in item.GetType().GetProperties())
        expando[propertyInfo.Name] = propertyInfo.GetValue(item, null);

    return expando;
}
```

So you can call:

```
var obj = new { foo = "hello", bar = 42, baz = new object() }.ToDynamic();

int value = obj.bar;
```

---

There are a hundred ways you can design an API for this, another one such (mentioned in orad's answer) is:

```
dynamic obj = new Expando(new { foo = "hello", bar = 42, baz = new object() });
```

Will be trivial to implement.

---

*Side note: there is always anonymous types if you know the property names statically and you dont want to add further after initialization.*

Answer (score 1):

Using the [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10402360/450913) from @samedave, and adding reflection, I got this:

```
void Main()
{
    dynamic foo = new ExpandoObject().Init(new
    {
        A = true,
        B = "Bar"
    });

    Console.WriteLine(foo.A);
    Console.WriteLine(foo.B);
}

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static ExpandoObject Init(this ExpandoObject expando, dynamic obj)
    {
        var expandoDic = (IDictionary<string, object>)expando;
        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo fi in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
           expandoDic[fi.Name] = fi.GetValue(obj, null);
        }
        return expando;
    }
}
```

But it would be nicer to be able to just do it like:

```
dynamic foo = new ExpandoObject
{
    A = true,
    B = "Bar"
};
```

> Please vote for this feature in Visual Studio [UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/7062098-support-object-initializers-on-expandoobjects).

**Update:**

Using Rick Strahl's [Expando](https://github.com/RickStrahl/Expando) implementation you should be able to do something like this:

```
dynamic baz = new Expando(new
{
    A = false,
    B = "Bar2"
});

Console.WriteLine(baz.A);
Console.WriteLine(baz.B);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to keep the simplicity of creating the intiial object like anonymous type with the possibility to be editable. My result is `.ToDictionary()` extension method

so change your code to use anonymous objects like:

```
dynamic obj = new
{
    foo = "hello",
    bar = 42,
    baz = new object()
};
```

and then call `.ToDictionary()` on that like:

```
dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject()
{
    { "foo", "hello" },
    { "bar", 42 },
    { "baz", new object() }
}.ToDictionary();
```

That way you have best of both worlds.

The extension method `.ToDictionary` is done through reflection:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static Dictionary<string, object> ToDictionary(this object obj)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        if(obj == null) return dict;

        // Get properties of the object
        var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach(var property in properties)
        {
            var value = property.GetValue(obj, null);
            if(value != null)
            {
                // Check if the property is of type IEnumerable but not string
                if(value is IEnumerable<object> && !(value is string))
                {
                    // Special handling for IEnumerable of primitive types or strings
                    if(value is IEnumerable<string> || IsEnumerableOfPrimitive(value))
                    {
                        // Add the entire list as is
                        dict.Add(property.Name, value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Otherwise, recursively convert each item in the list to a dictionary
                        var list = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                        foreach(var item in (IEnumerable<object>) value)
                        {
                            list.Add(item.ToDictionary());
                        }
                        dict.Add(property.Name, list);
                    }
                }
                else if(!property.PropertyType.IsPrimitive && !(value is string))
                {
                    // If the property is a complex object, recursively convert it to a dictionary
                    dict.Add(property.Name, value.ToDictionary());
                }
                else
                {
                    // If the property is a primitive type or string, add it directly
                    dict.Add(property.Name, value);
                }
            }
        }

        return dict;
    }

    // Helper method to determine if an object is an IEnumerable of primitive types
    private static bool IsEnumerableOfPrimitive(object obj)
    {
        if(obj is IEnumerable<object> enumerable)
        {
            foreach(var item in enumerable)
            {
                // Check if the item is not of a primitive type
                if(item != null && !(item.GetType().IsPrimitive || item is string))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```