# How to write JSON string value in code?

Tags: c#, json, string, syntax

I want to store the following string in a String variable

> {"Id":"123","DateOfRegistration":"2012-10-21T00:00:00+05:30","Status":0}

This is the code I use ..

```
String str="{"Id":"123","DateOfRegistration":"2012-10-21T00:00:00+05:30","Status":0}";
```

.. but it's showing error ..

Comment: Here it's pretty obvious but for the next question you should detail what error it's showing. It's the kind of precious information helping those wanting to help you.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You have to do this

```
String str="{\"Id\":\"123\",\"DateOfRegistration\":\"2012-10-21T00:00:00+05:30\",\"Status\":0}";
```

Please [see this for reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371232/Escaping-in-Csharp-characters-strings-string-forma)
Also [from msdn :)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

```
Short Notation  UTF-16 character    Description
\'  \u0027  allow to enter a ' in a character literal, e.g. '\''
\"  \u0022  allow to enter a " in a string literal, e.g. "this is the double quote (\") character"
\\  \u005c  allow to enter a \ character in a character or string literal, e.g. '\\' or "this is the backslash (\\) character"
\0  \u0000  allow to enter the character with code 0
\a  \u0007  alarm (usually the HW beep)
\b  \u0008  back-space
\f  \u000c  form-feed (next page)
\n  \u000a  line-feed (next line)
\r  \u000d  carriage-return (move to the beginning of the line)
\t  \u0009  (horizontal-) tab
\v  \u000b  vertical-tab
```

Comment: you shouldn't escape the final quote ;)

Comment: Thanks for this. If you've got a big JSON that you need to escape, use this tool: https://onlinetexttools.com/escape-text

Answer (score 50):

**C# 10 and lower**

I prefer this; just **make sure you don't have a single quote** in the string.

```
 var str = "{'Id':'123','DateOfRegistration':'2012-10-21T00:00:00+05:30','Status':0}"
              .Replace("'", "\"");
```

**C# 11 and upper**

You can simply put your json inside a pair of triple double-quote: """

```
var str = """
    {
        "Id": "123",
        "DateOfRegistration": "2012-10-21T00:00:00+05:30",
        "Status": 0
    }
""";
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON though

Comment: @mcont why it is not valid?

Comment: Because JSON requires strings to be wrapped with quotation marks (`"`) and not apostrophes (`'`). As far as I know most JSON parsers are quite strict about this

Comment: @mcont, Yes, definitely it must be a double quote not a single quote, that's why I append Replace ("'", "\"") at end.

Comment: @MohammadNikravan The problem with that is that if you have any single quotes in the string then it will produce unexpected results

Comment: @Ruzihm Yes, that's why I mentioned to make sure there is no single quote.

Answer (score 26):

Finetuning on [sudhAnsu63's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50668879), this is a **one-liner**:

With **.NET Core**:

```
string str = JsonSerializer.Serialize(
  new {    
    Id = 2,
    DateOfRegistration = "2012-10-21T00:00:00+05:30",
    Status = 0
  }
);
```

With **Json.NET**:

```
string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
  new {    
    Id = 2,
    DateOfRegistration = "2012-10-21T00:00:00+05:30",
    Status = 0
  }
);
```

There is *no need* to instantiate a `dynamic ExpandoObject`.

Comment: This is very clever. I think it's much cleaner than all the brute force string manipulations and escape sequences. I'll be using this method in my automated web API tests to build the sample request body.

Comment: Great answer, but imo second suggestion is for Newtonsoft.Json. And first is for Json.NET

Comment: @EugeneZakharov  Json.NET ↔ Newtonsoft

Comment: A nested demo version of this would be even better :)

Comment: True @OJB1  But only Javascript nested/inline snippets are possible!? ☝

Answer (score 14):

There is an alternate way to write these complex JSON using Expando object or XElement and then serialize.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2009/09/30/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject/

```
dynamic contact = new ExpandoObject
{    
    Name = "Patrick Hines",
    Phone = "206-555-0144",
    Address = new ExpandoObject
    {    
        Street = "123 Main St",
        City = "Mercer Island",
        State = "WA",    
        Postal = "68402"
    }
};

//Serialize to get Json string using NewtonSoft.JSON
string Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contact);
```

Comment: This approach worked quite well for me because I was writing unit tests for code that had to read in JSON files with various data conditions in them.  This gave me a lightweight and readable(!) way of creating a base object that I could easily reconfigure and tweak parameters on per test.

Comment: How did you manage to initialize the ExpandoObject this way? What I get: 'ExpandoObject' does not contain a defintion for 'Name' etc.

Comment: Reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478048/why-cant-i-do-this-dynamic-x-new-expandoobject-foo-12-bar-twelve explains that it is not possible!? 

Answer (score 14):

With Verbatim String Literals (`@"..."`) you can write inline multi-line json by swapping double quotes with pairs of double quotes - "" instead of ". Example:

```cs
string str = @"
{
    ""Id"": ""123"",
    ""DateOfRegistration"": ""2012-10-21T00:00:00+05:30"",
    ""Status"": 0
}";
```

Answer (score 8):

C# 11 introduces a new feature named [Raw string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#raw-string-literals). It makes working with JSON very easy. Just enclose the string using not one but three double quote characters (`"""`) as markers:

```
string str = """{"Id":"123","DateOfRegistration":"2012-10-21T00:00:00+05:30","Status":0}""";
```

Related YouTube video by Nick Chapsas: [Strings in C# 11 just got a whole lot better](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4KXWAgZE8xI).

Answer (score 7):

You have to escape the quotes within the string like this:

```
String str="{\"Id\":\"123\",\"DateOfRegistration\":\"2012-10-21T00:00:00+05:30\",\"Status\":0}";
```

Comment: Indeed, @MikeBarnes, but if you look closely at the timestamp you will see that my answer was posted 3 secs earlier - so please remove your comment and downvote.

Answer (score 2):

you need to escape the inner quotes like so:

```
String str="{\"Id\":\"123\",\"DateOfRegistration\":\"2012-10-21T00:00:00+05:30\",\"Status\":0}";
```

Answer (score 1):

For an out-of-box thinking solution, I encoded the JSON to base64 so it can be imported as a string value in one line.

This preserves the line formatting without you having to write dynamic objects or escape characters manually. The format is the same as if you read the JSON from a text file:

```cs
var base64 = "eyJJZCI6IjEyMyIsIkRhdGVPZlJlZ2lzdHJhdGlvbiI6IjIwMTItMTAtMjFUMDA6MDA6MDArMDU6MzAiLCJTdGF0dXMiOjB9";
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

//using the JSON text
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(json);
```

Comment: It might just be me, but I struggle to sight transpose the base64 encoding into json, making it a bit harder to tell what's going on in the code. Maybe others are more mentally adept than me. 