# Make mixed array variables?

Tags: c#, arrays, variables

I was wondering if I can add some variables in an array, and access them in a simply way like :

```
string[] ArrayName = {
    string abc;
    string varName;
}

//and later access them like:
Console.WriteLine(ArrayName[ab+"c"]);
```

Comment: Look into the `Dictionary` class.

Comment: Use Generic Collections to achieve something like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're just looking for a dictionary:

```
var ArrayName = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "abc", "something" },
    { "varName", "something" },
};

Console.WriteLine(ArrayName["ab"+"c"]);
```

---

**First Edit**

Alternatively, as you may be aware, C# lets you [overload operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx) like the indexer -- so if you wanted to, you could write a class that defines its own special behavior for `obj["string"]` (returning a member of the same name, or whatever else).

```
public class IndexableClass
{
    private string _abc = "hello world";

    public string VarName { get; set; }

    public string this[string name]
    {
        get 
        {
        switch (name)
        {
            // return known names
            case "abc" : return _abc;

            // by default, use reflection to check for any named properties
            default : 
                PropertyInfo pi = typeof(IndexableClass).GetProperty(name);
                if (pi != null) 
                {
                    object value = pi.GetValue(this, null);
                    if (value is string) return value as string;
                    else if (value == null) return null;
                    else return value.ToString();
                }

                // if all else fails, throw exception
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Property " + name + " does not exist!");
        }
        }
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    var ArrayName = new IndexableClass();
    Console.WriteLine(ArrayName["ab" + "c"]);
}
```

---

**Second Edit**

There are also *anonymous types* (`var ArrayName = new { abc = "something" };`), and [*dynamic types*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7478048/1001985), which you may find useful.

Comment: Doesn't the initialization need parentheses? `<string, string>() {`

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst actually parentheses are optional when you have the inline initialization `{ }`.

Comment: Good to know, wasn't positive on it.